# MPMoviePlayerController throws errors ONLY in universal app

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, universal

My app plays a video in fullscreen mode when the app is started. Everything is working flawlessly from 3.0 to 4.1.

However, if I compile the same code for a universal app, it will work on the iPad, but will not work on the iPhone (simulator) anymore.

Has anyone solved this problem?

Here's the code:

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:)]) {
  videoPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"portrait" ofType:@"mov"];
  videoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoPath];

  MPMoviePlayerController *aMoviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];
  self.moviePlayerController = aMoviePlayerController;
  [aMoviePlayerController release];  

  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(startVideo:) name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification object:nil];
  [moviePlayerController.view setFrame:self.view.bounds];
  [self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];

  moviePlayerController.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
 } else {
  //OS < 3.2
  videoPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"landscape" ofType:@"mov"];
  videoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoPath];

  MPMoviePlayerController *aMoviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];
  self.moviePlayerController = aMoviePlayerController;
  [aMoviePlayerController release];

  moviePlayerController.movieControlMode = MPMovieControlModeHidden;
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(startVideo:) name:MPMoviePlayerContentPreloadDidFinishNotification object:nil];
 }
```

And here's the error:

> -[MPMoviePlayerControllerOld view]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>
> 0x7924470

Even if I try to prevent this like so...

```
if ([moviePlayerController respondsToSelector:@selector(view)]) {
   [moviePlayerController.view setFrame:self.view.bounds];
  }
```

...the error is still thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same error few days ago. It needed only change the base sdk from 3.2 to 4.1
Hope it helps

Comment: Yup, that fixed it. Thank you, marcio!

Answer (score 1):

I have no explanation for the error, yet. But this seems to work (need to test on older devices):

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:)]) {
        videoPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"portrait" ofType:@"mov"];
        videoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoPath];

        /* NEW */
        MPMoviePlayerViewController *aMoviePlayerViewController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];
        aMoviePlayerViewController.moviePlayer.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
        aMoviePlayerViewController.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(startVideo:) name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification object:nil];
        [aMoviePlayerViewController.moviePlayer play];
        [self.view addSubview:aMoviePlayerViewController.view];
        self.moviePlayerController = aMoviePlayerViewController;


    } else {
        //OS < 3.2
        videoPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"landscape" ofType:@"mov"];
        videoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoPath];

        MPMoviePlayerController *aMoviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];
        self.moviePlayerController = aMoviePlayerController;

        aMoviePlayerController.movieControlMode = MPMovieControlModeHidden;
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(startVideo:) name:MPMoviePlayerContentPreloadDidFinishNotification object:nil];

        [aMoviePlayerController release];
    }
```

If only I could remember why I did it the other way in the first place ;)